# Angular Material MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE provider

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm updating Angular Material to it's latest version (beta-11) and it mentions that "md" prefix is being deprecated.

I used the tool they provide to update the project with this change, but I need to do the following, otherwise it won't work.

```
import {MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE} from '@angular/material';
```

And then, add it as a provider:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE, useValue: true},
    // ...
  ],
})
```

What does MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE do? Is this it really required from now on, or it's something that would need to be removed in the following release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE` ensures that only `mat` prefix is used for all selectors. It is required for now, but I think it will be removed in future releases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will wait until the next release to implement these changes then!

Comment: I upgraded to Angular 5 right now. Do I still need this provider? npm gives me an error that MATERIAL_COMPATIBILITY_MODE cannot be found.

Comment: Material 5 does not need that.